# What size should be returned from MeasureOverride

Tags: wpf, windows-store-apps

How control can say: I'll take all space that a parent will give me?

For example, my control is in ScrollVewer. It measures my control with size (Infinity, Infinity). My control shows small chart. Minimum size when a chart is still looks good is (300, 300). Maximum size is not restricted. What size my control should return from MeasureOverride() ? (0,0) or (300, 300)?

And what size the MeasureOverride method should return, when availableSize is accurate size, for examle (1234, 1235)?

This question is relevant for both WPF and Windows 8 XAML apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter of MeasureOverride is avaibleSize. As the name says this is the maximum size that the control can use/fill. The control should now return the real size it will use later. The returning size can be the full given size or less (e.g. the control always draws squares and need less space).

The game is a bit different with the ScrollViewer. The ScrollViewer pretends to have endless space and sets the availableSize to infinite. Now its up to the control to decide how big it is going to be or it likes to be. But the control must know it gets scrolled if the window is too small. Btw, returning 0/0 means your control doesn't need any space.

In your case scrolling a graph is propably not the best way. The way lain proposes is one way to address that: give your control the remaining space of your window and let your control scale within these boundaries.

Comment: my control may be used by others

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understand you right. Of course your control must handle availbleSize being infinite. As others already mentioned just return a size that makes sense (at least to some extend). But essentially its a slight misuse of your control. In all other cases just return the size you get and fill up that space.

Answer (score 2):

The correct solution is actually to return 0 size in MeasureOverride. Or whatever minimal size is required.

ArrangeOverride will then be called with the available size of ScrollViewer.

You can try it:

```
<Window x:Class="TestMeasure.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestMeasure"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <ScrollViewer>
    <local:MyTextBox Text="Hi"/>
  </ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

and

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace TestMeasure {
  class MyTextBox: TextBox {
    protected override System.Windows.Size MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size constraint) {
      Size baseSize = base.MeasureOverride(constraint);
      return baseSize;
    }

    protected override System.Windows.Size ArrangeOverride(System.Windows.Size arrangeBounds) {
      Size baseSize = base.ArrangeOverride(arrangeBounds);
      return baseSize;
    }
  }
}
```

Note that TextBox actually does return a size in MeasureOverride, but the ScrollViewer still passes its own size in Arrange.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could display your chart at least the size of 300x300, and make it bigger if you have more space. You could use ActualWidth and ActualHeight properties of Scrollviewer to make that sure.

Answer (score 0):

You usually do this using a `DockPanel` and setting `LastChildFill=True` like this:

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <ScrollViewer>
       <Button MinWidth="300" MinHeight="300"></Button>
    </ScrollViewer>
</DockPanel>
```